# dynamic programming grid problem approach solving using BFS

Tags: breadth-first-search

[image] We have an NxM grid, grid have one element named Bob. Bob can travel diagonally blocks only. The grid has some blocked blocks on which Bob can not travel. Write a function that returns on how many possible positions Bob can move. Solve this problem using BFS and submit the executable code in any programming language. In the following image example, Bob's positioning is at 9,3, and it can visit the places where Y is marked; hence your method should return 30.
Anybody any pseudocode or approach on how to solve this using BFS

Comment: Your question is lacking the image you cited, and is lacking any code too. I'm posting you some [material](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/) you can use to study BFS in different programming languages.

Comment: added picture please if you can give some code

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution is modified version of solution given by ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/10987431/dominicm00 ) on problem ( [Using BFS to find number of possible paths for an object on a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723818/using-bfs-to-find-number-of-possible-paths-for-an-object-on-a-grid) )

Map.java:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Map {
public final int width;
public final int height;

private final Cell[][] cells;
private final Move[] moves;
private Point startPoint;

public Map(int[][] mapData) {
    this.width = mapData[0].length;
    this.height = mapData.length;

    cells = new Cell[height][width];
    // define valid movements
    moves = new Move[]{
        new Move(1, 1),
        new Move(-1, 1),
        new Move(1, -1),
        new Move(-1, -1)
    };

    generateCells(mapData);
}

public Point getStartPoint() {
    return startPoint;
}

public void setStartPoint(Point p) {
    if (!isValidLocation(p)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid point");

    startPoint.setLocation(p);
}

public Cell getStartCell() {
    return getCellAtPoint(getStartPoint());
}

public Cell getCellAtPoint(Point p) {
    if (!isValidLocation(p)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid point");

    return cells[p.y][p.x];
}

private void generateCells(int[][] mapData) {
    boolean foundStart = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapData[i].length; j++) {
            /*
            0 = empty space
            1 = wall
            2 = starting point
             */
            if (mapData[i][j] == 2) {
                if (foundStart) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have more than one start position");

                foundStart = true;
                startPoint = new Point(j, i);
            } else if (mapData[i][j] != 0 && mapData[i][j] != 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map input data must contain only 0, 1, 2");
            }
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(j, i, mapData[i][j] == 1);
        }
    }

    if (!foundStart) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No start point in map data");
    // Add all cells adjacencies based on up, down, left, right movement
    generateAdj();
}

private void generateAdj() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
            for (Move move : moves) {
                Point p2 = new Point(j + move.getX(), i + move.getY());
                if (isValidLocation(p2)) {
                    cells[i][j].addAdjCell(cells[p2.y][p2.x]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isValidLocation(Point p) {
    if (p == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Point cannot be null");

    return (p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0) && (p.y < cells.length && p.x < cells[p.y].length);
}

private class Move {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Move(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}}
```

Cell.java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Cell {
public final int x;
public final int y;
public final boolean isWall;
private final LinkedList<Cell> adjCells;

public Cell(int x, int y, boolean isWall) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x, y must be greater than 0");

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.isWall = isWall;

    adjCells = new LinkedList<>();
}

public void addAdjCell(Cell c) {
    if (c == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cell cannot be null");

    adjCells.add(c);
}

public LinkedList<Cell> getAdjCells() {
    return adjCells;
}}
```

MapHelper.java:

```
class MapHelper {
public static int countReachableCells(Map map) {
    if (map == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments cannot be null");
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[map.height][map.width];

    // subtract one to exclude starting point
    return dfs(map.getStartCell(), visited) - 1;
}

private static int dfs(Cell currentCell, boolean[][] visited) {
    visited[currentCell.y][currentCell.x] = true;
    int touchedCells = 0;

    for (Cell adjCell : currentCell.getAdjCells()) {
        if (!adjCell.isWall && !visited[adjCell.y][adjCell.x]) {
            touchedCells += dfs(adjCell, visited);
        }
    }

    return ++touchedCells;
}}
```

Grid.java:

```
public class Grid{

public static void main(String args[]){
    int[][] gridData = {
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0}};  //2 is bobs position, 1 is blocked, 0 can be visited
        
    Map grid = new Map(gridData);
    MapHelper solution = new MapHelper();
    System.out.println(solution.countReachableCells(grid));

}}
```

For original answer of similar problem visit ([Using BFS to find number of possible paths for an object on a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723818/using-bfs-to-find-number-of-possible-paths-for-an-object-on-a-grid)) for original answer.